# Linux kernel module programming: makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While learning Linux kernel modules I can see (so far from two sources) two ways for writing Makefile. The first is something like:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
        obj-m := module.o
else
default:
        $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
endif
```

The latter is less complex:

```
obj-m := module.o
all:
        $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
```

Either makefile compilation leads to **successfully compiled module**. My learning is accompanied with the LDD3 book and what I have read so far from it is the next one:

> This makefile is read twice on a typical build. When the makefile is invoked from the command line, it notices that the KERNELRELEASE variable has not been set. It locates the kernel source directory by taking advantage of the fact that the symbolic link build in the installed modules directory points back at the kernel build tree. If you are not actually running the kernel that you are building for, you can supply a KERNELDIR= option on the
>   command line, set the KERNELDIR environment variable, or rewrite the line that sets
>   KERNELDIR in the makefile. Once the kernel source tree has been found, the makefile
>   invokes the default: target, which runs a second make command (parameterized in
>   the makefile as $(MAKE))to invoke the kernel build system as described previously.
>   On the second reading, the makefile sets obj-m, and the kernel makefiles take care of
>   actually building the module.

If the makefile is read twice then the second approach should lead to recursion, isn't it?

Comment: Recursion (in this context) is defined as one instance of Make invoking another instance of Make. So the second approach involves recursion. If you are asking whether the second approach leads to an infinite loop, the answer is no, because the second instance of Make has "modules" as a target, not "all". Does that answer your question?

Comment: Beta, you should post that as an answer and not a comment.  I'd upvote you.  I would add that both approaches use recursion to work, but the first result makes it slightly more obvious that the "default" or "all" rule will not be called on the second pass.

Comment: @Beta, can you explain in more details how exactly this isn't leads to recursion inside make? Possibly post your answer and I will upvote you ^^. (Watching the source code of kbuild's Makefile can't get me to the point where I can figure out the internals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call the Makefile for the first time by typing `#make` on the console you are not passing any target.
So, It will call the target name `all:` in the makefile by default.

Inside the `all:` target you are passing the target as modules.So, this time it will build the modules instead of going to `all:` targets.

SO its not going to be infinite Recursion.